# I was using 'beeware'. While using briefcase create android i got the following permission error

Tags: python, android, beeware

I used `briefcase create android` but it shows pemission error. I am using windows command prompt for all this. Can someone tell what can I do to resolve this error

```
Downloading OpenJDK8U-jdk_x64_windows_hotspot_8u242b08.zip...
################################################## 100%
Installing AdoptOpenJDK...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alok\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\Alok\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Alok\beeware-tutorial\beeware-venv\Scripts\briefcase.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\alok\beeware-tutorial\beeware-venv\lib\site-packages\briefcase\__main__.py", line 11, in main
    command(**options)
  File "c:\users\alok\beeware-tutorial\beeware-venv\lib\site-packages\briefcase\commands\create.py", line 677, in __call__
    self.verify_tools()
  File "c:\users\alok\beeware-tutorial\beeware-venv\lib\site-packages\briefcase\platforms\android\gradle.py", line 57, in verify_tools
    self.android_sdk = AndroidSDK.verify(self)
  File "c:\users\alok\beeware-tutorial\beeware-venv\lib\site-packages\briefcase\integrations\android_sdk.py", line 119, in verify
    jdk = JDK.verify(command, install=install)
  File "c:\users\alok\beeware-tutorial\beeware-venv\lib\site-packages\briefcase\integrations\java.py", line 223, in verify
    jdk.install()
  File "c:\users\alok\beeware-tutorial\beeware-venv\lib\site-packages\briefcase\integrations\java.py", line 279, in install
    java_unpack_path.rename(self.command.tools_path / "java")
  File "C:\Users\Alok\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\pathlib.py", line 1287, in rename
    self._accessor.rename(self, target)
  File "C:\Users\Alok\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\pathlib.py", line 393, in wrapped
    return strfunc(str(pathobjA), str(pathobjB), *args)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\Alok\\.briefcase\\tools\\jdk8u242-b08' -> 'C:\\Users\\Alok\\.briefcase\\tools\\java'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey dear try copying the file/folder
From here: 'C:\Users\Alok\.briefcase\tools\jdk8u242-b08'
To Here: 'C:\Users\Alok\.briefcase\tools\java'
This might help you
Thanks